# How are push notifications be transmitted to the device?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

In the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW7) Apple states

> Important: In iOS, Wi-Fi is used for push notifications only if there
>   is no cellular connection or if the device is an iPod touch. **For some
>   devices** to receive notifications via Wi-Fi, the device’s display must
>   be on (that is, it cannot be sleeping) or it must be plugged in. The
>   iPad, on the other hand, remains associated with the Wi-Fi access
>   point while asleep, thus permitting the delivery of push
>   notifications. The Wi-Fi radio wakes the host processor for any
>   incoming traffic.
>
> Sending notifications too frequently negatively impacts the device’s
>   battery life—devices must access the network to receive notifications.

What is meant with "for some devices"? Are that iPods and iPhones without cellular connection?

If I get this correctly always the cellular connection is used. If not available Wi-Fi is used under certain circumstances (as stated above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"For some devices" means that the rule applies sometimes but not always. Apple isn't intendng to list devices for you in dogwhistle and isn't binding itself to any particular behaviour now or in the future. The words have no meaning other than their natural meaning. Though the examples you posit sound like two likely examples.

Otherwise your interpretation seems correct. It seems to be: use the mobile network if available; otherwise use Wifi if available. Some sleeping devices may have neither.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, cellular connection is always preferred. When cellular is not available, WiFi is used if the device is connected to the WiFi network.

That "for some devices" comment simply means that for some devices the WiFi connection may only exist when the device is either plugged in or the display is on. This means that those devices won't get notifications while asleep if cellular connection is not available. I'm assuming they are referring to iPods and iPhones.